# How to get 1 row in pivot table?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 I have table pivot table defined :

```
Schema::create('article_vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
    $table->foreignId('vote_id')->references('id')->on('votes')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
    ...
});
```

and having in both models methods with  belongsToMany
I can refer articles of a vote as :

```
$voteArticles = $vote->articles;
```

I got all related articles, but how can O get only 1 row if I have $articleId ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved in a number of ways by [querying the relations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

```php
$vote->articles()->where('id', $articleId)->first();

$vote->articles()->whereKey($articleId)->first();

$vote->articles()->find($articleId);

$vote->articles()->findOrFail($articleId);
```

Or in your example, you already have a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#main-content) of articles. We can also do this:

```
$vote->articles->find($articleId);

$vote->articles->findOrFail($articleId);
```